# PHP to AS400 Connection via ODBC/PDO error from browser

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, db2, ibm-midrange

I am trying to establish a connection between a linux server and our AS400 to query the DB2 database. I installed and configured both unixODBC and the iSeries Access drivers. When using `isql` with a DSN specified in `/etc/odbc.ini` the connection goes through fine. When I run `php -f connect.php` the connection works as well, but when I browse to `http://localhost/connect.php` i get the following message:

**exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[01000] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib64/libcwbodbc.so' : file not found' in /srv/http/connect.php:25 Stack trace: #0 /srv/http/connect.php(25): PDO->__construct('odbc:DRIVER={iS...', '', '') #1 {main}**

I am assuming it must be a permission issue... But I am not sure how to go about it. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Ok after reading a bunch of posts online I'm starting to see the misunderstanding here... when the php page says "can't open lib '/opt/ibm/etc...' it assumes the path is in /srv/http/opt/ibm/etc...' rather than starting from the root... The issue is that the path is provided by the file `odbcinst.ini` and read as is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the solution and I'll post it for anyone who needs it.

Creating a symbolic link to the driver files in /usr/lib/ solves the issue.

`sudo ln -s /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib64/* /usr/lib/*`

After that Apache/PHP will be able to locate the file without hiccups.

Hope it helps.